# How do I send network packets from an ipv4 address (with port forwarding) to an ipv6 address (no port forwarding) without STUN?

Tags: router, nat, ipv6, port-forwarding, ipv4

*** I have the following situation: ***

Bob wants to interact with Alice directly (encrypted interaction, no intermediary server who will forward his packets). Both are behind NAT. Alice has a public ipv6 address and an ipv4 address (behind non-symmetric NAT). Bob has an ipv4 address with ipv4 port forwarding, but Alice does not have port forwarding of her ipv4 traffic. Bob knows Alice's ipv6 address and her current ipv4 address and Alice knows Bob's public ipv4 address. Bob wants to initiate a network communication with Alice directly, but Alice's private ipv4 address is not reachable behind NAT. Bob must try to reach Alice's ipv6 address from his ipv4 address. How can Bob get to Alice? Is 6to4 the solution?

*** Background information: ***

Alice and Bob are both running a peer-to-peer application (that I am in the process of developing). This peer to peer application, at startup, tries to open up Alice and Bob's ipv4 ports. The uPnP (universal plug and play) port opening library works on Bob's router with its ipv4 internet, but not on Alice's router with its dual ipv4/ipv6 internet. That is why Bob has his ipv4 ports opened when he runs the application but Alice does not. Let's say that STUN and TURN are not availible - Bob wants to initiate a direct connection with Alice without using an intermediary server (STUN or otherwise) to facilitate the connection. How would Bob go about doing that, (assuming that both Alice and Bob are both behind NAT and neither of their NATs are symmetric NAT)?

*** BIG CLARIFICATION ***

Bob isn't literally sending ipv6 packets from an ipv6 address. Alice's internet has both ipv4 and ipv6 (Alice can reach ipv6 enabled/ready websites, like Google, and she can reach sites that only offer ipv4). So if Alice types "what is my ip" into Google, she gets an ipv6 address (try it). But if she goes to http://checkip.amazonaws.com (try this too - it is not ipv6 enabled), she will only get her ipv4 address. I was wondering if it was possible for Bob to wrap ipv6 packets destined for Alice with his ipv4 packets (ipv6 over ipv4, or 6to4) as a means of NAT traversal.

*** What do I mean by "no-middle-man"? ***

I mean no TURN forwarding or any other form of forwarding in which an intermediary server receives a copy of the packet destined for Alice and forwards that copy to Alice.

*** If Alice has an ipv4 address, and Bob and Alice know one another's ipv4 addresses, why doesn't Bob just send packets from his ipv4 address to Alice's ipv4 address? ***

Bob has port forwarding and Alice does not have port forwarding. Even if Alice is waiting for a connection on private port 30000, when Bob sends a packet from his public port 30000 on his ipv4 address to Alice's public port 30000 her ipv4 address, Alice's NAT will not let Bob's packet go through.

Comment: *Is 6to4 the solution?* Nope - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6to4 *6to4 _does not_ facilitate interoperation between IPv4-only hosts and IPv6-only hosts. 6to4 is simply a transparent mechanism used as a transport layer between IPv6 nodes.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirement for no middle man can be interpreted in different ways. And which exact interpretation is being used does make a difference, because certain interpretations will in combination with the other requirements result in an impossible set of requirements.

Considering the ISP providing internet connectivity to each endpoint to be a third party that cannot be relied upon is obviously too strict to allow for communication. But even if we include the routers on the IPv4 path between the endpoints in the infrastructure we can rely upon, it remains impossible due to the other requirements:

- Bob wants to initiate the connection.
- Bob can only send IPv4 packets.
- Bob does not know any IPv4 address to send the packets to.

If we interpret the no middle man requirement to simply say that the bulk of the traffic must not be routed through a third party, but it is acceptable to involve a third party in connection setup, then it is possible.

Bob can send a packet to a third party on a public IPv4 address asking for a message to be send to Alice' IPv6 address asking Alice to connect back to Bob over IPv4. In any new protocol design intended to be future proof, I would only use the IPv4 connection between the endpoints as a means of tunneling IPv6 packets and then let all the higher layers deal only with IPv6.

**Which IPv6 tunnel protocols might be suitable**

Let's consider the following options for Bob getting an IPv6 address that can be used for the bulk transport: 6to4, 6rd, 6in4, native, Teredo, home grown.

Lack of support from Bob's ISP immediately rules out 6rd and native.

The requirement for no third party rules out 6in4 unless one of the ISPs on the direct path between Alice and Bob offers 6in4 which Bob can use. Such service is unlikely to exist on the direct path, and if it did would require more configuration on Bob's part, then I think you'd be willing to.

The requirement for no third party also means that 6to4 and Teredo are potentially problematic.

Anything using protocol 41 is difficult to get through a NAT. And even if you can get it to work through a NAT, it can in most cases only support a single user behind the NAT. Given that Alice can't even get a port forwarding, we can pretty much rule out using protocol 41 end-to-end. Thus goes 6in4 and 6to4 as possible end-to-end communication.

Setting up anything based on protocol 41 requires administrator privileges on the endpoint where you are configuring it. This is another argument against 6in4, 6rd, and 6to4. A tunnel based on UDP can be built directly into the application because UDP ports can be opened by an unprivileged application.

Using 6to4 on Bob's side with native IPv6 on Alice' side means relays must be used. Since I argued that Alice can't send protocol 41 packets, Alice would have to rely on a relay operated by somebody else. With a bit of luck Alice' ISP has a relay, but you can't rely on that. It is not much better in the other direction since Bob's ISP doesn't support IPv6 at all, they are unlikely to have any relay either. So 6to4 in this scenario is likely to have problems in both directions. That rules out 6to4.

What we are left with from the starting list is Teredo or homegrown. If Bob uses Teredo, his first packet will be sent to a Teredo server chosen by Bob. Since Bob can choose which Teredo server to use, the use of a third party would be less of a problem. If a third party turns out to be unreliable, Bob can simply switch to another.

But that only covers the first packet from Bob to Alice. The return path is a bit problematic. If you simply rely on the default routing, then the return traffic from Alice will go to a Teredo relay operated by Alice' ISP or much more likely a third party relay. If Alice' ISP has deployed enough Teredo relays to handle their customers' traffic and they are paying attention to the stability of the relays, then Teredo would reliable in this scenario. However such ISPs are rare.

Alice could decide to run her own relay. But connectivity between Teredo client (running on Bob's computer) and Teredo relay (running on Alice' computer) is usually opened from client to relay. That is the direction, which did not work for you.

There is a deprecated mode of operation in Teredo in which connections can be opened in the other direction from relay to client.

This means you could build a Teredo client directly into your software and in the specific setup you describe have it use this deprecated mode on Bob's computer. On Alice' end your software runs on a native IPv6 address, but at the same time your software must detect peers using this deprecated mode of Teredo and when detected attempt to send packets directly to the peer using a Teredo relay build directly into your software.

One caveat you have to pay attention to is that when the first echo request from Bob is sent through a Teredo server to Alice, it will be processed by the IPv6 stack in the OS on Alice computer rather than by your application. That means it will be tricky to get the reply routed through a Teredo relay build into your software.

If you take this approach I strongly recommend that you write your software to support sending packets either through your build in Teredo code or through the ordinary route. And periodically probe both ways to send packets such that you will always be using the most reliable of the two.

It's a bit ironic, that of all the standard protocols I can think of, the one which fits your requirements the best happens to be a deprecated variant of Teredo. Even more so considering that Teredo is usually considered to be unreliable. That said, I truly believe that under the exact circumstances you describe, it could be made to work reliably.

**A possible homegrown solution**

You could pick a /80 prefix of RFC 4193 address space to use in your application, and use the last 16 bits of the IPv6 address to embed IPv4 address and port number of a tunnel endpoint.

With that approach, Bob would have an IPv6 address which Alice could send packets to. The problem with this approach is, that Bob would not have any way to send IPv6 packets to Alice before having reached the first IPv6 packet from Alice.

Also being homegrown, there are no public servers which can relay those packets from Bob to Alice. So this particular homegrown approach would be like Teredo except that the problem about insufficient infrastructure would be amplified.

Based on that, I am thinking that if you want to go with a homegrown solution, you are more likely to get a good result by taking Teredo as a starting point and try to improve it rather than building a homegrown solution from scratch.

Comment: @SachaTRed In my answer I was specifically not assuming Bob had any native IPv6 access. I was however considering a wide variety of tunnel solutions. Using IPv6 over IPv4 or 6to4 would mean protocol 41 packets, which are unlikely to work through Alice' NAT, because according to your question she doesn't even have access to configure a port forwarding on said NAT.

Comment: "Bob does not know any IPv4 address to send the packets to." - Sorry, I made a mistake. In addition to knowing Alice's public ipv6 address, Bob also knows Alice's public ipv4 address (the address Alice gets when she goes to:  http://checkip.amazonaws.com ). Does this change the situation?

Comment: @SachaTRed Probably not. Knowing the IPv4 address isn't going to help, if there are no port forwardings to get a packet through the NAT to Alice.

Comment: So just use a Toredo or homegrown server in the middle to forward the first packet from Bob to Alice. In the process, pass Bob's ipv4 address to Alice. Then Alice can reply to Bob's request with ipv4 traffic. The "middle man" only needs to forward a single packet to establish an end-to-end connection. Is that is?

Comment: @SachaTRed Having IPv6 support at just one end of the connection is of very limited use. But you definitely need to to support IPv6 for the cases where both ends have IPv6. The scenario you describe for Alice is going to get more and more common. If Bob's connection looked like Alice' then IPv6 would be much more reliable than IPv4.

Comment: @SachaTRed Yes. A middleman on dual stack to forward first packet from Bob to Alice is the way to go in the scenario you describe. The middleman could be a Teredo server or you go with something homegrown.

Comment: I understand. But that didn't confirm or deny the last thing I said. Say between Alice and Bob there is Carol. Carol has both a public ipv4 address and a public ipv6 address. Bob sends a packet to Carol saying that he wants to initiate a connection with Alice. Carol passes that packet to Alice's ipv6 address, notifying Alice that Bob at ip address 12.34.56.78 wants to communicate. Alice then starts sending packets from her ipv4 address to 12.34.56.78 and Bob replies to those ipv4 packets from Alice. Would that would be a valid way to establish a peer-to-peer connection?

Comment: @SachaTRed If you know for a fact that an IPv4 port is forwarded to Bob, then yes it will work. You might need to pass along not only Bob's IP address, but also the port number.

Answer (score 3):

What you ask is impossible without somebody in the middle. You can only use IPv6 if both sides have IPv6 and you cannot accept incoming connections behind NAT without port forwarding.

Comment: It is possible to pull it off with only a single packet being passed to someone in the middle. But yes, without passing a single packet to any intermediary server, it would be impossible. Thank you for your answer.